# Camera doesn't work on Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian, camera, pi-zero, raspbian-buster

Pi version: 1.3, camera revision: 1.3. Correctly connected.

OS: Raspbian lite buster. Freshly installed. The firmware is updated to the latest one with `rpi-update` and the system too with `apt update && apt full-upgrade`.

The camera interface is enabled via `raspi-config`.

`/boot/config.txt` contents:

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
start_file=start_x.elf
fixup_file=fixup_x.dat
```

Rebooted but still having:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: raspistill or raspivid also doesn't work ?

Comment: mmal: Camera is not enabled in this build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled

Comment: After reboot your camera is always enable in raspi-config ? Also check if any another programm not already use the camera.

Comment: It asks "Would you like the camera interface to be enabled?" again? Should it show something else? No programs are running since it's a fresh install of the OS.

Comment: Have you open raspi-config with sudo ?

Comment: Sure. It changes /boot/config.txt properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107782/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-fey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually it worked after I reinstalled the OS changing it to the regular GUI version from the Lite one. I didn't run `rpi-update` again since the new firmware had been already installed.

Not sure whether it's because of some issue with the Lite version either just the system needs to be reinstalled after the firmware update but anyway now `vcgencmd get_camera` shows `supported=1 detected=1` and `raspistill` works.

Thanks to Ephemeral for the help.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.